# .NET FormsAuthentication Generic Principal from Authentication Ticket

Tags: c#, asp.net

Does anyone know how to add a generic principal to the HTTPContext from the Forms Authentication Ticket?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do this in the `Application_AuthenticateRequest` event. [Here's an example](http://www.xoc.net/works/tips/forms-authentication.asp):

```
protected void Application_AuthenticateRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var user = HttpContext.Current.User;
    if (user == null || !user.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        return;
    }
    // read the roles from the cookie and set a custom generic principal
    var fi = (FormsIdentity) HttpContext.Current.User.Identity;
    var fat = fi.Ticket;
    var astrRoles = fat.UserData.Split('|');
    HttpContext.Current.User = new GenericPrincipal(fi, astrRoles);
}
```