# FormsIdentity IsInRole returning incorrect value- what am I missing?

Tags: asp.net, security, forms-authentication

[image]

Shouldn't the `IsInRole` check above return `true`? The method signature is

`bool IsInRole(string role);`

Could someone give brief explanation why here it is returning false? It seems like something obvious however can't seem to point out.

Comment: Please right click and view image to see it bigger. Sorry for adding the image, but I just want to give context to the question being asked here.

Comment: Why are you so sure it should return true? Do you actually have a role named 'ResetPassword'?

Comment: @santiagoIT: Yes, see `Ticket.UserData` value which is coming from the `IPrincipal`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the role is stored in the user data portion of the authentication cookie. But the `IsInRole` method doesn't look in it when checking for roles unless you tell it to do so. You may take a look at the [following answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5170730/29407) for an example of how to do so (in this example I have assumed that the roles are stored in the user data portion of the authentication cookie and separated by a `|` => this is done when the user logs in).

Comment: Thanks Darin, that helped. Turns out there is a place where I am doing `GenericPrincipal gPrincipal = new GenericPrincipal(formsIdentity, null);` - I will try passing the roles when I new up the gPrincipal now, so that the `IsInRole` check will work. Does that sound like the missing part to you as well?

Comment: @VoodooChild, that totally and absolutely sounds like the missing part of your puzzle :-)